# Ruby on Rails update current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I update current user information, I have tried but showing this error:

> When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.

This is my controller code:

```
 def edit
    @user = current_user
  end

 def update
    @user= current_user
   if @user.update_attributes(params[:current_user])
    # Handle a successful update.
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

My routs:

```
get 'edit' => 'users#edit'
post  'edit'   => 'users#update'
```

Params:

```
private

def user_params
  params.require(:users).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email)
end
```

My model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
before_save { email.downcase! }

validates :first_name, :presence => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
validates :last_name, :presence => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, format: { with: /\A[^@\s]+@([^@.\s]+\.)+[^@.\s]+\z/ }

has_secure_password
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for :user, url: my_account_path(@user), action: :update, method: :post  do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
    <%= f.submit "Update Account" %>
<% end %>
```

That would help me a lot, please.

Thanks

Comment: Post your `params` value

Comment: Hi @RAJ, Post updated

Comment: Thanks, look at the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34576231/1047207

Comment: please post your form.

Comment: Hi @spickermann, post updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to modify your `update` statement to look like:

```
@user.update_attributes(user_params)
```

This will update permitted attributes of the user.

Answer (score 5):

You are unable to update your user for two reasons: First, your form posts the data in the `params` nested under a key named `user` (instead of `current_user`):

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

Second, in your model you validate the presence of a password, but your form does not provide a password. Have a look at the [documentation of `has_secure_password`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html). There is no need for that extra validation. Therefore just remove the line:

```
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
```

Comment: Also, read up on using [strong parameters](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/) - especially for something sensitive like user details.

Comment: Hi @spickermann Thanks, but solution not working. same problem

Answer (score 2):

The correct way would be to use the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resource :user, path: "", only: [:edit, :update] #-> url.com/edit

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      @user = current_user #-> you don't really need this
   end

   def update
      if current_user.update user_params
        # do something
      else
        render :edit
      end
   end

   private

   def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:x, :y, :z)
   end
end
```

Comment: Hi @ich Peck Thanks, but attribute not saving

Comment: So can you post your params, form and user model?